# WkWebView how manage events and window launched by input type file

Tags: ios, swift, webview

This is my first app to iOS and i do the same app to Android without problems and now i'm stucked to this problem.

When the user click on "choose file" into webview the phone ask me where i want pick the photo (or file), and if i select "Close" the entire WebView get closed!
How can i manage that events? (image below show the windows that take me this problems)
Same problem if i click to a loaded attachment a appear a window that show me the image and if i long press the image some buttons appear (copy, download or close).... if i press one of them the WebView get closed...

The back button is disabled because the user can't use back in this case and must follow the workflow forced by webview.

I try with this code but still close the webview

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MyWebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    //Variable used for take received data from other ViewControllers
    var urlString = String()
    var callerString = String()
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if callerString == "CodeController"{
            backButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            backButton.isEnabled = true
        }
        
        myWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(myWebView)
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        myWebView.load(URLRequest(url : url!))
    
    }
    
    @IBAction func backButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if callerString != "CodeController"{
            if myWebView.canGoBack{
                myWebView.goBack()
            }else {
                //Go to Main View
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backOnViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here some `images` of which `buttons` close the entire `WebView` and how manage them in a different way?

[image: button that close entire View]
[image: Another button that close entire View]

Comment: I don't really follow what is causing your wkwebview to dismiss.  You're loading the wkwebview with a url to a file and it's triggering a download?   Perhaps look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate and you can log out the various navigation events to see what is happening?

Comment: @Augie i call an url like that for localhost test: ht tp:// 0.0.0.0:8069/Mobile/checkCode?code_to_check=[here inputed code]

I will try to intercept what you mean...but i'm new to Xcode and app ios... if you have more suggestions to help i'm here...
Thanks
(Added spaces on url for break link)

Comment: No one can help me to manage this windows to prevent the Entire ControllerView to close?

Comment: "Ok think that the problem is related on "Close actions" into window that appear when i upload file into <input type="file"> or when i click on attachment link." But you have not shown any of that code.

Comment: @matt i haven't that code it's all managed by wkwebview... how can i manage that code?
How can i say to that "close button" don't close the entire viewcontroller but only the window for load attachment and go back to webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug from WkWebView libraries.
To avoid that just upgrade OSX and XCODE to last versions and the problem is solved.

Not sure if it's solved for all iOS OS but sure for iOS 12, and maybe 10